# MacBook taking a long time to move stuff to trash

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra

I have some small files, screenshots really that my MacBook mid-2015 High Sierra is taking a long time to move to trash.

What could be the problem?

Comment: There could be a process that could be running with your trash folder. (Although unlikely) Like 'empty' process could be stuck at some point without showing you the errors. Are other folders fine at moving files?

Comment: @VictorFran, yes I did notice that other files were okay to trash.